# WPF/Catel: TextBox doesn't fire TextChanged event when Shift + character is entered

Tags: wpf, mvvm, catel

i got the following XAML:

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"
      Width="300"
          Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay,
                    UpdateSurceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  
          ToolTip="Suchbegriff eingeben.">
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
              <catel:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SearchTxt_TextChangedCmd}" 
                               DisableAssociatedObjectOnCannotExecute="False"/>
         </i:EventTrigger>    
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </TextBox>
```

It's a textbox which is bound to a string in mvvm.
The problem is when i press "shift + a character" at the first letter then the event is not fired.
When i press caps lock + any character, then the event will be fired as usual.
It alsow works when i press any character on the keyboard.

Can anyone help me please?

Thx in advance,

Edit: Solution after the suggestion of Geert:

In the view.xaml:

```
<TextBox Height="31" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
         Margin="0,59,20,0" 
         Name="textBox2" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         Width="282"
         Text="{Binding BehaviorText, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <catel:UpdateBindingOnTextChanged UpdateDelay="200" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

In the ViewModel (using Catel):

```cs
public String BehaviorText
{
    get { return GetValue<String>(BehaviorTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(BehaviorTextProperty, value); }
}


public static readonly PropertyData BehaviorTextProperty =
    RegisterProperty("BehaviorText", typeof(String), null, (sender, e) => ((MainWindowViewModel)sender).OnUpdateBindingOnTextChanged());

private void OnUpdateBindingOnTextChanged()
{
    Console.WriteLine(BehaviorText);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the UpdateBindingOnTextChanged behavior instead. If that doesn't fit your needs, please create a repro and upload it at https://catelproject.atlassian.net

Comment: Hi Geert, thx for the answer :). Do you mean repro=reproduction of the error? Sorry for asking because my English is not that good. Ok will try the suggestion out and then upload the example project if it will not work.

Comment: Hi, i tried my user defined EventoToCommandClass and it works with trigger. I will upload the repro on https://catelproject.atlassian.net

Comment: Thanks! Repro is indeed a reproduction.

Comment: Fixed the issue, currently releasing a new nightly build. This fix will be officially available in Catel 3.7.